# What's the general state of speech recognition right now?

Tags: speech-recognition

I'm currently evaluating the cyrrebt state of speech recognition (SR) technology, and it seems that there are quite a few APIs and services springing up.

My own experience of SR is that keyword matching works well with multiple speakers, and dictation works OK with trained speakers in very controlled environments.  Is this still true?  Are there any good approaches for doing speech to text of arbitrary audio files - could be keyword matching from audio streams for indexing or could be an attempt at full transcription.

Does anybody have any comments on the comparison of nuance versus other engines versus the open source solutions?

Comment: Question should probably go to programmers.SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While newer and friendlier applications designed around speech recognition will continue to be written, speech recognition itself has reached a brick wall. The accuracy of even the best engines drops quickly in the presence of noise, a big problem for smartphone users who often use the technology in noisy environments.

A bigger and related problem is that speech recognizers cannot pick out a single voice in a roomful of voices (the cocktail party problem), something that most humans handle with relative ease. Until someone solves this problem, I'm afraid that speech recognition technology will not advance much. It's a billion dollar problem because a solution will make every existing speech recognition engine obsolete almost overnight.

Comment: right, so not much different than last time i looked except iterative improvements to regognition algorithms then.

Comment: I would like to add to this that Kinects open mic speech recognition at a distance, is a pretty big step in solving the cocktail party problem.  Even if you do not play video games I would recommend trying out Mass Effect 3 (or reading up on it).  That game has loud background audio.  What they did with voice commands and game play was pretty cool, even more so because it worked without a push to talk solution.